# DNS record not added when server joins domain

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I've brought up three Windows 2012 VMs inside of an OpenStack cloud. I configured the first one as a domain controller, named "dc" (domain: internal.lorinhochstein.org), and then I joined the other two instances (server-1, server-2) to the domain.

When the first instance joined the domain, a DNS "A" record was added on the domain controller, but when the second instance joined the domain, no such recorded was added:

```
PS C:\ProgramData> Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName "internal.lorinhochstein.org" -RRType "A"

HostName                  RecordType Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData
--------                  ---------- ---------            ----------      ----------
@                         A          6/8/2013 8:00:00 PM  00:10:00        10.40.1.4
dc                        A          0                    01:00:00        10.40.1.4
DomainDnsZones            A          6/8/2013 9:00:00 PM  00:10:00        10.40.1.4
ForestDnsZones            A          6/8/2013 9:00:00 PM  00:10:00        10.40.1.4
SERVER-1                  A          6/8/2013 9:00:00 PM  00:20:00        10.40.1.5
```

What could cause a record to fail to be added to the DNS server?

Comment: What are your DNS settings on server-2 set at?

Comment: The DNS server was pointed at the domain controller. However, the "connection-specific DNS suffix" was not "internal.lorinhochstein.org", it was something else. This is because the DHCP server it's using is different from the domain controller, and had a different string there. Could that be causing the problem?

Comment: If that's the case, on the DNS server you'll probably see logs stating that it was trying to update its client records but couldn't find that dns suffix zone to create the client's A records.